# Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js, npm-run

I trying starting the my priject on next.js,  but z get this mistake in console and don't undestand what i need do it

May be who know it, what this the problem?

````
> work@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
info  - Using webpack 4. Reason: future.webpack5 option not enabled https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at Object.618 (/Users/dima/Documents/Work project/work/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-scss/scss-syntax.js:1:100)
    at __nccwpck_require__ (/Users/dima/Documents/Work project/work/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-scss/scss-syntax.js:1:11735)
    at Object.270 (/Users/dima/Documents/Work project/work/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-scss/scss-syntax.js:1:413)
    at __nccwpck_require__ (/Users/dima/Documents/Work project/work/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-scss/scss-syntax.js:1:11735)
    at Object.327 (/Users/dima/Documents/Work project/work/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-scss/scss-syntax.js:1:260)
    at __nccwpck_require__ (/Users/dima/Documents/Work project/work/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-scss/scss-syntax.js:1:11735)
    at Object.845 (/Users/dima/Documents/Work project/work/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-scss/scss-syntax.js:1:3733)
    at __nccwpck_require__ (/Users/dima/Documents/Work project/work/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-scss/scss-syntax.js:1:11735)
    at /Users/dima/Documents/Work project/work/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-scss/scss-syntax.js:1:11863
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/dima/Documents/Work project/work/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-scss/scss-syntax.js:1:11889)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)```
````

Comment: I have the same issue coming from scss-syntax.js. Did you install any packages before running npm run dev ?

Comment: I was able to resolve the error by running ```yarn```